# postDelayed handler with loop

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I did some research and tried some code including the code below from [Android postDelayed Handler Inside a For Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024588/android-postdelayed-handler-inside-a-for-loop).

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 


    int count = 0;
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 

            // need to do tasks on the UI thread 
            Log.d(TAG, "runn test");


            if (count++ < 5)
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

        } 
    }; 

    // trigger first time 
    handler.post(runnable);
```

But the count variable will show an error because it is accessed within the inner class. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variable 'count' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final**

you need to Transform `count` into final One element array

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final int[] count = {0};        //<--changed here
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // need to do tasks on the UI thread
        Log.d(TAG, "runn test");


        if (count[0]++ < 5)     //<--changed here
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

    }
};

// trigger first time
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Comment: Is it normal to do like this? Or should avoid if possible?

Comment: this is necessary if you want to access that variable